Career switch from a Data Scientist to a Cryptologist

I have a question about my Cryptography Stack Exchange post: Career switch from a Data Scientist to a Cryptologist
I am currently working as a Data Scientist, and I hope to do a career switch to cryptography as I have become interested in cryptography research. I currently have a bachelor's degree in mathematics as well as working experience as a Data Scientist.
What is the best way to do a mid-career switch for a Data Scientist? During my time working as a Data Scientist, I have lots of experience with Statistics and working on Datasets as well as with Machine Learning models.
On top of that i have experiences working with Databases as well as some Software design/developer skills. Is my background relevant and useful for a carrier switch to become a Cryptologist?
Are my skillsets as a Data Scientist useful and transferable to Cryptography. My aspirations in my lifetime has always to become both a Data Scientist and a Cryptologist. Would that be possible? Also will there be any intersection between the roles of a Data Scientist and a Cryptologist?
And what other skills do i have brush up and pick up on in order to make this switch? Given the background i already have.
Im looking for this Cryptologist job in Particular
https://www.csit.gov.sg/join-us/job-opportunities/job-detail/cryptologist
